# Css menu moving when Bxslider changes slides

Tags: css, bxslider

The last few days i was creating alone the website for my company (private ambulance). I was learning during the process and i was thinking that the only thing left to finish it was to write the content of some pages.

But today i found a strange error, bug , mistake still don't know.

I bought a new laptop yesterday with windows 8 and i downloaded the latest version of chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 m. When Bxslider changes slides (every 2 seconds) 2 submenus of the main menu (ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΕΣ and ΠΡΩΤΕΣ ΒΟΗΘΕΙΕΣ) are moving.

Same thing happens on the footer.

Why is this happening? It doesn't happen on my other laptop with windows 7 and firefox or chrome (same version 27.0.1453.110 m).

Have i done something wrong? Is this a bug?

I almost forgot the website: http://hellasambulance.gr

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); 
to the affected elements fixed my problem. Found it in a discussion about another slider. I still didn't understand why this is happening.